# Why does the reciprocal of a polynomial divided by another polynomial not have a remainder?

Tags: polynomials

From a question in my textbook:
Given that $\,f(x) = 8x^3 + 4x -3$, find the remainder, if it exists, when $\frac1{\,f(x)}$ is divided by $x + 1$.

The answer states that the remainder does not exist. Does this mean that the reciprocal of any polynomial does not have a remainder when divided with another polynomial? If that's the case, why?

Comment: Well...what would it mean?  when you divide one polynomial, $g(x)$ by another, $h(x)$ you write $g(x)=h(x)\times q(x)+r(x)$ where $q(x)$, the quotient, and $r(x)$, the remainder are both polynomials and the degree of $r(x)$ is less than the degree of $h(x)$.  How would you define it for rational functions?

Comment: You could make a case that the remainder is $0$, as we can obviously write $\frac 1{f(x)}=(x+1)\times q(x)+0$ where  $q(x)=\frac 1{(x+1)f(x)}$ is rational.  That's not a very interesting construction, though.  The remainder would always be $0$ as the reciprocal of a rational function is again rational.  Just as the remainder on dividing one rational number by another is always $0$.

Comment: If the remainder were to be written as $r(x)$, then wouldn't  $\frac1{(x+1)\,f(x)} = q(x) + \frac{r(x)}{x+1}$, and wouldn't there still be a remainder?

Comment: What's $q(x)$ meant to be?  If we allow $q(x)$ to be a rational function then just take $q(x)=\frac 1{(x+1)f(x)}$ so $r(x)=0$.

Comment: Think about the ordinary rational numbers.  What's the remainder if you divide $\frac 12$ by $3$?

Comment: I'm actually not very clear on what the remainder of $\frac{1}{2}$ divided by $3$ is. Because $\frac{1}{2}\div3 = \frac1{6}$, is it $1$?

Comment: Well, if you allow rational quotients (like $\frac 16$) as you have to, then the remainder is clearly $0$ as every non-zero rational divides every rational.

Comment: @lulu ahh I think I understand this now. So the remainder of any rational number divided by a rational number is always 0, because it would just result in the form $\frac{a}{b}$?

Comment: Well, I'd prefer to say that the remainder isn't defined in that context.  Like I said in an earlier comment, you can declare that the remainder exists and is always $0$ but that doesn't seem like much of a definition.  I prefer to say that the remainder is defined only when you have something like the division algorithm.